# can i use a hardware nic without going through a xen brdge?

Tags: virtualization, xen

I want to use a hardware nic in a domu machine and preferably not go through a bridge, right now i have three nics and tree bridges set up with xen. they all use their own peth.

I am having troubles with a router that is run as a domu and it would be nice if the domu ciuld accesss the nic directly without having to go through a xen bridge.

So, if it is possible, how can i male a domu use a hardware nic without going through a xen bridge?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try PCI passthrough.
A good post about this: http://forums.opensuse.org/install-boot-login/400984-xen-passthrough-nic.html

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to bridging that doesn't involve PCI passthrough is routing:

http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetworking#head-740e3cf58c2ac48051f74c4f72cc6df52117e87e

That way the NIC can remain unbridged on the dom0. You just route and optionally NAT all traffic from the virtual interface to the outside network, and back of course.